# Как изменить междустрочный интервал TextView android

Tags: android, android-layout

В разметке есть текстовое поле и картинка,  я поставил выравнивание картинки по нижнему краю текста, но картинка по факту ниже текста! Как можно изменить междустрочный интервал в TextView, пробовал подставлять разные значения в lineSpacingExtra или lineSpacingMultiplier но результата не увидел. Есть какие то варианты?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="02:35:11"
        android:textSize="65sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_spam"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_marginRight"
        android:src="@drawable/spam_ico"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textView_timer"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Comment: Мне думается, что выравнивание по вертикали по центру тут будет лучше смотреться.

Comment: @pavlofff во всяком случае это было бы проще реализовать. Но это только часть верстки, если смотреть в целом то лучше все таки смотрится с выравниванием по-низу, но только не в таком виде как на картинке.

Answer (score 1):

Это не междустрочный интервал. Это запас для символов, нижняя часть которых рисуется ниже строки. Например `gjyq,_`.
Убедиться в этом вы можете просто добавив один из этих символов в ваш `TextView`.
Вычислять его не имеет смысла, т. к. на разных устройствах шрифт может быть разным.

Comment: т.е. нету такого свойства в котором я мог бы прописать значение "0dp" и границы виджета  и границы текста стали бы а одном уровне? Эту проблему только падингом решить можно?

Comment: @KirillStoianov, границы виджета и границы текста совпадают. Там нет отступов. Там есть только резерв для "хвостиков" определенных символов вниз, как и для заглавных букв вверх. Вы с этим ничего не сделаете

Comment: да, в смысле  - запас для символов.

Answer (score 0):

Для выравнивания можно воспользоваться параметром для ImageView:

```
android:paddingBottom = "8dp"
```

Comment: ну это был очевидный вариант. я думал мож как то в верстке можно указать конкретно размер этого интервала!

Answer (score -1):

Нужно бэкграунд у `textview` обнулить. Это уберет отступы по краям и снизу и Ваш `textveiw` будет занимать только область с самим текстом.

Comment: это инфа 100 % ?))

Comment: Сорян, спутал с `edittext`